# Possible to install magento into a non-public directory?

Tags: php, magento, directory

I have several websites in my `/`

I publish the websites into `/website` folder (from the root) and i don't want to publish all in `website/magento`. I would like to publish only the essentials in `website/magento` for security reasons.

Is it possible? How should I do it?

**I have read:**
[Magento; private/public filesystem layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238923/magento-private-public-filesystem-layer)

but it's not exactly what I am asking.

Thanks

Comment: You should just be able to install it into a subdirectory the same way you would the root directory. We do it at work all the time on our development server. You'll just need to modify the .htaccess file.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand this:
"i would like to publish in website/magento only the essential"
What precisely do you need visible and what do you need protected?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, should test, I think it should be possible.

In index.php change

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
```

to

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
```

The essential things are skin, media, downloader, errors, js folders about others I am not sure.

I am not sure whether you need this at all, because file you want to protect and covered by chmod and .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Modify `.htaccess` file which is available in Magento root directory like below:

```
<Directory /website/magento >
   deny from all
   allow from 192.168.0.50
</Directory>
```

This directive will protect the `magento` folder from everybody except 192.168.0.50 IP address which is this IP can use magento.